# Random некорректно работает в цикле C#

Tags: c#, случайные-числа, список, стеганография

Есть код, который считывает размеры изображения, после чего должен создавать три случайных ключа ( значения которых не выходят за количество пикселей изображения по вертикали и горизонтали, то есть выбирать случайные пиксели изображения), добавлять их в список, а затем записывать в файл.

```
        private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OpenPictureBox.Image != null & textMessage.Text != null)

        {
            SavePictureBox.Image = OpenPictureBox.Image;
            SavePictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            string text = textMessage.Text;
            byte[] bittext = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text); //преобразовали текст в байты
            BitArray bits = new BitArray(bittext); //преобразовали байты в биты                       
            Bitmap container = new Bitmap(OpenPictureBox.Image);
            Bitmap fullcontainer = new Bitmap(container);
            int n = container.Height;
            int m = container.Width;
            int r = 3; //количество раз, которое сообщение будет записываться в контейнер


            //СОЗДАНИЕ КЛЮЧА
            List<List<List<int>>> keys = new List<List<List<int>>>(); //создаем пустой массив для ключей
            StringBuilder keysstr = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
            {
                List<List<int>> key = new List<List<int>>(); //пустой массив для каждого из трех кючей
                for (int j = 0; j < bits.Length; j++)
                {
                    List<int> k = new List<int>();
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    int k1 = rnd.Next(10, m - 10);
                    int k2 = rnd.Next(10, n - 10);
                    k.Add(k1);
                    k.Add(k2);
                    keysstr.Append(Convert.ToString(k1));
                    keysstr.Append(" ");
                    keysstr.Append(Convert.ToString(k2));
                    if (j < bits.Length - 1)
                    {
                        keysstr.Append(",");
                    }
                    key.Add(k);
                }
                //key.Sort();
                keys.Add(key);
                if (i < r - 1)
                {
                    keysstr.Append(";");
                }
            }
            //записываем ключи в файл
            string fileName = "keys.txt";
            FileStream aFile = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(aFile);
            aFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            sw.WriteLine(keysstr.ToString());

            sw.WriteLine(bits.Length.ToString());
            sw.WriteLine(m.ToString());
            sw.WriteLine(n.ToString());

            sw.Close();
   }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что по итогу, весь список состоит из первого пикселя, полученного в этом фрагменте кода

```
                    List<int> k = new List<int>();
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    int k1 = rnd.Next(10, m - 10); //значение пикселя по горизонтали
                    int k2 = rnd.Next(10, n - 10); //значение пикселя по вертикали
                    k.Add(k1);
                    k.Add(k2);
```

Пробовал обнулять переменные k1 и k2 в конце цикла, но это ничего не меняет. При этом кусок кода, генерирующий ключ, скопированный в отдельно созданный файл и основанный на случайно взятых значениях из головы (а не на основе изображения) работает корректно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно ознакомится с документацией C# [`Random`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8).

Если в кратце, при создании `new Random()`, условно, этот объект уже содержит все случайные числа, сгенерированные на основе "зерна". В конструкторе без параметров "зерном" является текущее время.

Ваш цикл выполняется почти в одно мгновение, и "зерно" (то есть время) одно и то же. А значит и случайные числа тоже одинаковы.

Для решения проблемы нужно вынести создание объекта `Random` за пределы цикла и использовать в цикле этот один объект.

А вообще, хорошей практикой считается создавать объект `Random` один раз за выполнение программы (например сделать его статическим). Так будет исключена возможность повторов случайных чисел, если очень быстро вызвать метод OkButton_Click несколько раз.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за такой развернутый ответ!
Только начинаю знакомиться с C#, и пока что не все нюансы получается учитывать и успевать охватить. Постараюсь избежать этого в будущем, но ваш ответ дичайше помог, спасибо!